# geoserver layaerpreview internalerror? unknown WKB type 12 . in openlayers

Tags: types, gis, qgis, geoserver, wkb

internal error unknown  WKB type 12
in geoserver  layaer preview using load openlayers
in geoserver using i am create a web mapping application but some layers are seen only when i am zoom in

[image]